# Snapshot Dependency - don't run pending changes on dependencies

Tags: teamcity

Assume I have three build configurations

1. Build and Run Tests
2. QA Build
3. Production Build

QA depends on Build And Run Tests.  Production depends on QA.

The normal workflow is as follows.

1. Commit change
2. Build and Run Tests runs automatically
3. Run QA Build manually.
4. QA approves changes
5. Run Production Build manually.

This works great.  However, let's assume a change is committed some time between step 3 and 5.  So now I have 1 change pending for QA, and 2 pending for Production(1 of which is approved by QA).

If I click the **Run** button in TeamCity, it will run the pending change for the QA Build and both changes for the Production Build.

If I click the "..." on the **Run** button, I can then click "Changes" and pick a specific revision to include in this build.  However, this does not show me which revision is currently in QA.  So now I have to check which revision QA has approved and make sure I pick the correct one.

Is there something like the way Artifact Dependencies work?  In that I can specific "Last Completed" or "Last Pinned".  This will ensure that unapproved changes are not included in a build.

Comment: Have you checked version 7? There's some new support for build pipelines if I'm not mistaken, that might do eat you want.

Comment: Nothing stood out in the documentation.  I'm currently waiting for the my admin to install it.  If you can point me to something specific, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I think @Lasse meant [build chains](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Chain)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific scenario you should define [snapshot dependency](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Snapshot+Dependencies) from **2** to **1** and from **3** to **2**. When QA is willing to test artifacts made by **1**, they can go to the ["Build Chains"](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Chain) tab (as @neverov just mentioned) of either **1**, **2** or **3** and run **2** and **3** manually from there. This ensures same changes are used in all chain steps.

You can also define [artifact dependency](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Artifact+Dependencies) between those configuration (from **2** to **1** and from **3** to **1**) so that binaries built by **1** are passed to **2** and **3** without having to re-create them.

Comment: This appears to be new to TeamCity 7.  I'm on 6.5.  This however looks to be exactly what I want.  If I don't get any responses for 6.0 / 6.5, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I've faced similar issue: How do I use the SnapShot dependency to say that I want build B to use the same VCS rev as build A, but when running build B, I don't want build A to be run again, since the version it wants to build is already built successfully for A. It seems that the only way to use Build Chains is to run every single step.

Comment: When adding "Snapshot Dependency" to B make sure "Do not run new build if there is a suitable one" checkbox is checked (that's the default). In this case A won't run if it already contains build with corresponding sources.